# How to use select_circle in a modal operator to select faces in edit mode?

Tags: add-on, selection-tools

I'm trying to write a small tool where I can "paint" a face selection and at the same time expand this selection to its shell (essentially what select_linked() does.

I have set this up as a modal operator and selecting works fine while using:

```
self.loc = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]
bpy.ops.view3d.select(location=self.loc, extend=True)
```

Sadly I can't seem to get it to work with select_circle.
Simply doing:

```
bpy.ops.view3d.select_circle(event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y, 10)
```

Gives me an exception: 1-3 args execution context is supported exception

I then tried to override the context like so:

```
override = context.copy()
override["x"] = event.mouse_region_x
override["y"] = event.mouse_region_y
override["radius"] = 10
bpy.ops.view3d.select_circle(override)
```

but this does not do anything..

```
bpy.ops.view3d.select_circle('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

selects but then the select_linked() does not work anymore :/

```
bpy.ops.view3d.select_circle('EXEC_DEFAULT')
```

also doesn't seem to work.

The complete code for the addon is here: https://gist.github.com/sschoellhammer/bcafcb2cdec2e2aee08c6c0837a88559

I'm sorry, I'm still fairly new to blender scripting. If you have any pointers for me, please let me know!

Thanks so much!
seb

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out..
from:
([Is there a way to set the radius of the new circle select tool by python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170466/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-radius-of-the-new-circle-select-tool-by-python-script))

```
def get_3d_area_and_region(self):
    self.view_3d_area = None
    self.view_3d_region = None
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:  # Cycle through all the avaliable areas
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":  # if area is called VIEW_3D
            for region in area.regions:  # Cycle through all the regions in that area
                if region.type == "WINDOW":  # if the region is WINDOW
                    self.view_3d_area = area  # save the area and region in variables
                    self.view_3d_region = region
                    return
    print ("Could not find area/region")
```

and then

```
override = context.copy()
            override['area'] = self.view_3d_area  
            override['region'] = self.view_3d_region
            bpy.ops.view3d.select_circle(override, x=event.mouse_region_x, y=event.mouse_region_y, radius=100)
```

I still don't really understand why the context area information of my own operator is not enough and I still have to query all the areas extra. Oh well, some day I will know more..:)